Migrate org.springframework.oxm.xmlbeans.XmlBeansMarshaller to latest version
I have the following code:
Gradle dependencies:
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-oxm:4.1.7.RELEASE'
implementation "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:3.4.2"

code:
import org.springframework.oxm.xmlbeans.XmlBeansMarshaller;

@Bean
public HttpMessageConverter<Object> createXmlHttpMessageConverterSettings() {
    MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
    XmlBeansMarshaller marshaller = new XmlBeansMarshaller();
    .....
    xmlConverter.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    xmlConverter.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);

    return xmlConverter;
}

When I update the Gradle dependencies to versions:
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-oxm:6.1.10'
implementation 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:4.0.4'

this import import org.springframework.oxm.xmlbeans.XmlBeansMarshaller; is missing.
Do you know how I can properly migrate this code?

You don't as that class has been removed. So you will have to move to a different marshaller (I believe only the Jaxb2Marshaller and XStreamMarshaller are the ones that are left for now). See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18369

hm... which one can you recommend? Jaxb2Marshaller or XStreamMarshaller?

Asking for recommendations isn't allowed on stackoverflow and the answer would be opinionated as well. Check yourself. Another option is to copy the XmlBeansMarshaller sources from Spring 4.3 to your own project and maintain it yourself.
